# Prevent Element-UI from enforcing list-item for li tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am rendering some list data like this:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="el in elements">
        {{el.data}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in my `.css`:

```
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0;
}

li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 10px;
}
```

When I add a `Select` component from Element-UI, it enforces `list-item` display property on my `li` element as well. I want my list to render as inline-block. How can I override Element's styling of the `li` elements?

Working demo: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/xRYoNw

Comment: Please create a working example

Comment: @Dekel added demo.

Comment: Check the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your `ul` a specific `id` and use that `id` in your css:

```
ul#list1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul#list1 li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

And in your html use:

```
<ul id="list1">
```

This is the update to your codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoRgOx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="ele_type" class="form-control">
    <div v-for="el in elements">
        <option 
            value="{{el.data}}"
        >
            {{el.data}}
        </option>
    </div>
</select>
```